# Google CDN and PoP locations

Tags: cdn

I'm under great confusion whether Google having CDN service or not. Some sources saying Google having CDN services. But I'm unable to find the Google's name in any CDN services list.

If Google having CDN service, I want to know all the locations of its PoP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Points_of_presence)

List of CDN services : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Answer (score 3):

The information of Google's CDN PoPs is hard to come, but in a speech at the Open Networking Summit 2014 last March, Amin Vahdal showed a slide with their locations.

You can see the speech and briefly the slide in minute 15:35 of this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4gOZrUwWmc

Answer (score 1):

Google now provides an [exhaustive list of Edge PoP](https://peering.google.com/about/delivery_ecosystem.html)s.

As written in this link, they also have an "Edge Caching Infrastructure" that belongs unknown (but isn't really a part of Google infrastructure) :

> Google runs an edge caching platform on top of our network
>   infrastructure. The caching platform also has elements within ISP and
>   access networks. The elements within these networks are called Google
>   Global Cache (GGC), and they enable operators to deliver Google
>   content closer to users, reducing transport costs and increasing
>   performance

Answer (score 0):

As of today Google published it under "Locations": 
https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/locations

These sites are sometimes referred to as points of presence or POPs. Google connects its network with other network operators at [numerous edge](https://peering.google.com/#/infrastructure) POPs around the world, including many of the Cloud CDN sites listed above.